# Abstract classes, why can't we declare private val and var class member?

Tags: scala

```
abstract class Table {
  private val records: Int
}
```

Is it because we have to create an instance of an abstract class before we can access its private member?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would imagine this is because there is no way to make them concrete:

```
class Foo extends Table {
    override val records = 3
}
```

would fail, because `records` is private to `Table`.

It would make `Table` kind of useless. I can't see that it would *hurt* anything, just it almost certainly indicates a mistake by the programmer.

Answer (score 19):

To extend a bit on @Owen's answer: you *can* declare private members.

```
abstract class Table {
  private val records: Int = 0
}
```

But you can't declare abstract private members. Why? Because any concrete class which extends an abstract class must override any abstract members, and it can't override a private member. So you couldn't have any concrete classes which extend `Table` at all.